# Masonry layout is not a constructor error

Tags: angular, typescript, masonry

Hi everyone running into an error in my Angular web app with masonry and was wondering what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error: masonry_layout_1.default is not a constructor

```
import Masonry from 'masonry-layout';

let grid = document.querySelector('.grid');

let msnry = new Masonry(grid, {
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 20,
    gutter: 0
});

msnry.layout();


<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <component-name></component-name>
  <component-name></component-name>
  <component-name></component-name>
  <component-name></component-name>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `masonry-layout` is a module that can be imported?

Comment: pls provide 'masonry-layout' content

Comment: Mike McCaughan: It was importing fine previous to an angular cli update from "@angular/cli": "^1.5.5" to "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",

Answer (score 3):

You should import masonry with:

```
import * as Masonry from 'masonry-layout';
```

Comment: Works also with symfony + encore + webpack + typescript.